# He was incognito? She was incognita?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

1) Should the adjective/adverb *incognito* be used only for males? [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/) says:

> Definition of **incognita**
>   :  [...]  —used only of a woman

But M-W's definition of *incognito* simply says

> with one's identity concealed

So is *incognito* truly unisex ? What about plurals/mixed-sex/unknown - are they all *incognito* too?

On [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20was%20incognita%2Che%20was%20incognito%2Cshe%20was%20incognita%2Cshe%20was%20incognito&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Che%20was%20incognito%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20was%20incognito%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20was%20incognito%3B%2Cc0) I see  hits for *he was incognito* but negligible hits for *he/she was incognita* or *she was incognito*.

2) Since it has a Latin root and from what  I can  figure out from Wikipedia, in Latin the feminine **and neuter** versions are both the same, i.e. *[incognita](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/incognita#Latin)*, so, it seems strange English default is *[incognito](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/incognito#Latin)*?

Comment: Both *simpatico* and *loco* are in the dictionary, but not *simpatica* and *loca*. I don't see why we shouldn't treat *incognito* the same way.

Comment: English words derived or adapted from Latin (or romance languages) often alter or ignore the original gender.

Comment: "it seems strange English default is incognito" - you're expecting logic from English?

Comment: I guess you could say *incognita* if you wanted, but since English is not Latin, you shouldn't have to. Also, with respect to what @Peter said, one could still, taking a cue  from Spanish, say, in English,  that "She was loca" and one wouldn't be breaking the law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pair incognito/incognita came to English through Italian, which is why it doesn't match up with Latin cases. Italian, of course, got the word from Latin, hence the Latin root. (You can see this this on the Merriam-Webster pages for [incognito](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incognito) and [incognita](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incognita).)

---

Currently, I would say that *incognita* is going the same path as other feminine-exclusive words such as *authoress*: disuse. Most people would not think twice about using the word *incognito* for anyone, whereas *incognita* will probably raise eyebrows, and may even be considered offensive.

Just use *incognito* for everyone, and avoid pushing into the issue of [gender-neutral language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_English).

Comment: I didn't not think that the gender declination  has ever been a problem for "incognito" in the English language, apart from those who wanted just to make a point of its Latin origin.

Comment: @JOSH I'm not sure what your point is... (Also, this has nothing to do with the *Latin* origin, which would be incognitus. The o/a ending came from Italian, like I said.)

Comment: English's masculine/feminine usage based directly on the Italian equivalent does indeed make sense to me. I guess the fact that Latin, (in this case at least - bearing in mind I'm illiterate regarding Latin) has a variant for neuter  (which perhaps would have served English well) was long lost by the time these words came to English.

Answer (score 5):

***[Incognito](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/incognito_2)*** is an adverb meaning: *in disguised or under an assumed name*,  and has no gender declination in English.

"This [term](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/incognito) is said especially of great personages who sometimes adopt a disguise or an assumed character in order to avoid notice."  (Wiktionary)

> - in a way that prevents other people from finding out who you are.
>
>   - *Movie stars often prefer to travel incognito.*

Note that the feminine term incognita was used  in the past as suggested by [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=incognito):

> - ***Feminine form incognita*** was maintained through 19c. by those scrupulous about Latin.

Word Origin

> - *mid 17th cent.: from Italian, literally ‘unknown’, from Latin incognitus, from in- ‘not’ + cognitus, past participle of cognoscere ‘know’.*

OLD

Curiously, also the Italian idiomatic expression "[in incognito](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/in-incognito)"  which corresponds to the English usage, has no gender declination.

De Mauro

Comment: Does the same this hold true for plural forms as well; to those scrupulous, should it be *incognitos* in the movie stars example?

Comment: +1 Can't believe the Latinists  insisted on *incognita*!  I guess we can, but don't have to, jettison that idea, except in translated phrases  such as *[terra incognita](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=terra+incognita&allowed_in_frame=0)*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: the plural for those who are scrupulous would be *incogniti* (masculine) or *incognite* (feminine).

Comment: @Alan Carmack I asked for a ruling on this issue in a comment a few days ago. Had I asked it as a question, I would have accepted your answer. By the way, is it ok to pronounce "incognito," as an English word, with the stress on "cog" and the "ni" with a short i? With these Latin words, I seem to want a long vowel sound where most others use a short vowel (e.g. caveat) and a short vowel in incognito where most others use a long e.

Comment: @Airymouse: not only is it OK, it's the stress pattern that [prescriptivists often prefer](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtojrMr0Ft4C&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=incognito+stress&source=bl&ots=FMJBXNcenk&sig=o6vEfsY7dvOqX8XzsN8gh823jD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv1pjEudbQAhVC2oMKHWz_D7AQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=incognito%20stress&f=false) due to the etymology of the word.